# MultiDict Error Django

Tags: python, ajax, django

Im using Django and trying to get a response by using AJAX. I have two forms, the first one works just fine. Though I use the same logic in my second form handling it does not work well.

**models.py**

```
class AskMe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

**views.py**

```
def AskMeQ(request):
    if request.method == POST:
        name = request.POST['name']

        AskMe.objects.create(name=name)
```

**urls.py**

```
url('r^askmeQ/$', views.AskMeQ)
```

**ajax logic**

```
$('.former').on('submit', '.ajaxform', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/askmeQ/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {name: $('#name').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken
        }
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
        $('.formset').slideToggle(400)
        });
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
});
```

#### ERROR

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  77.             list_ = super().__getitem__(key)

During handling of the above exception ('name'), another exception occurred:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/pc/Django_Projects/vikas/vikas/views.py" in askmeQ
  40.         name = request.POST['name']

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  79.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /askmeQ/
Exception Value: 'name'
```

The logic I use above used to work in all the previous forms, but here it throws me an error. 
The SQLite3 table has been created as `projectname_model.name`.

How can I correct this?

Comment: You need to at least show the Ajax code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the name was not posted with the request. Due to which, you `name = request.POST['name']` will throw an error since the key won't be part of the `POST` dict.

To correct this, alter your code to:

```
def AskMeQ(request):
    if request.method == POST:
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        if name:
            AskMe.objects.create(name=name)
        # else:
        #     error condition handling
```

Comment: This does not throw an error, but it registers a **None** type in the database.

Comment: @PoornaChandra If this is happening for all your requests, then the problem is obviously with the ajax logic. Your current question seemed like the MultiDict issue, for which I've already answered. You should probably ask a fresh question, with the logic for form and the ajax request, and accept an answer on this one.

Comment: I've updated my AJAX logic... Sorry I forgot to add the class name in my ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use path() instead of url() in urls.py